# Change position of control buttons in Win7 from register?

Tags: windows-7, regedit

How to change position (from right to move left) of control buttons (close, max, min) in Win7 from register?

Comment: In general, you can't. Applications have the option to override whatever you setup.

Answer (score 0):

with KDE under linux you can even define which button has to be showed and where!
I know (but never tested) that they are doing KDE for windows.
Try looking into http://kde.org.
ciao
   matteo